# Tablesorter Pager not working in Safari or Chrome

Tags: jquery, safari, google-chrome, tablesorter, pager

I am building an app using the tablesorter plug-in and it's pager plug-in. Things work perfectly fine in Firefox and IE, but in Safari (4.0.4 on a PC) and Chrome () I get errors when it hits the following code that binds the tablesorter pager. I took the pager binding out and it worked, so something is going wrong somewhere in those three lines of code.

`var tableSel = calendarportlet.ut.createIdSelector(calendarportlet.addNamespace("eventListTable"));

var pagerSel = calendarportlet.ut.createIdSelector(calendarportlet.addNamespace("pager"));

jQuery(tableSel).tablesorter({

                     widthFixed: true,

                     headers: { 0: {sorter: false} },

                     sortList:[[2,1],[1,0]],

                     widgets: ['zebra']

                 }).tablesorterPager({ <-- error happens in here

                     container: jQuery(pagerSel),

                     positionFixed: false

                 });`

Also, the errors only happen in Safari and Chrome when prototype.js is loaded AFTER jQuery. If they are loaded before jQuery, it works fine. However, this is a portlet and it has to play nice with other portlets, so we don't want to modify the header and loading order of the js libs. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: We had a similar issue and are using older versions of jQuery and prototype (don't ask...). In our case it was that the data in the columns being sorted wasn't consistent. Some values in a column were date strings, while others were placeholders of "---". As soon as we changed to sort on a column with consistent data (all numeric or empty columns) everything seemed to work fine on Chrome and Safari without updating any js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded Prototype and now everything works. I now get a "$ is not a function" error in Firebug, but everything seems to work ok.